# How to Authorize or limit user for not to subscribe and publish particular Topic in ejabberd MQTT module?

Tags: mqtt, ejabberd, ejabberd-auth

I am using ejabberd 19.02 for MQTT communication between client. 
I can Authenticate user using "external"  auth method - by just validating user name and password.

I also have requirement that one  user is allowed to publish one topic and another user is not allowed to publish that topic.  The same for the subscription as well.   I believe it is Authorization or Access control.
How to achieve above in the ejabberd MQTT server  ?

I saw "Access rules" configuration but it seems it not matching with topic subscription/publish limitation to some users.

Can it be controlled like Authentication - like give responsibility external

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module `mod_mqtt` provides two options for access control: `access_subscribe` and `access_publish`. The former can be used to restrict access for subscribers and the latter can be used to restrict access for publishers. Both accept mapping `filter: rule` where `filter` is an MQTT topic filter and `rule` is the standard ejabberd access rule.

As an example, let's say `user1@domain.tld` is only able to publish to topic "/foo/bar/" and its subtopics, while `user2@domain.tld` is only able to subscribe to this topic and its subtopics. The configuration will look something like this:

```
acl:
  ...
  publisher:
    user:
      "user1" : "domain.tld"
  subscriber:
    user:
      "user2" : "domain.tld"

modules:
  ...
  mod_mqtt:
    access_publish:
      "/foo/bar/#":
        - allow: publisher
        - deny
      "#":
        - deny
    access_subscribe:
      "/foo/bar/#":
        - allow: subscriber
        - deny
      "#":
        - deny
```

Comment: Thank you. This reply Almost matching with my expectation. Still one doubt. We will be having million users and user is dynamic. So we can't add user name into yml file. How to handle this dynamic user addition scenario ? Does ejabberD has extensions so that i can check user's jabber id and  control access publish and subscriber